# Exists a way to free memory in atexit or similar without using global variables?

Tags: c, free, fclose, atexit

I am developing a project in C, and I need to free the allocated memory and also close all the open files before it exits.

I decided to implement a `clean` function that will do all this stuff and call it with `atexit` because there are a lot of possible exit scenarios.

The problem is that `atexit` doesn't allow me to set functions with parameters, so I can't send to `clean` the pointers that need to be freed in the end of the process.

So I need to declare as global variables every pointer that may need to be freed, and every file that may remaining open in the program? (I already did that but doesn't looks good) or does exist a similar function to `atexit` that allows to send parameters? or more probably there is another way that I am missing?

Comment: You only need one variable that points to you memory pool. That seems acceptable.

Comment: If you're on a modern consumer operating system then all resources will be released when you exit. That means all allocated memory will be freed, all open files will be closed, etc.

Comment: Also, if you have e.g. files that need to be open during the whole process runtime, then you probably also access it in multiple places, and that means it's already a global variable, or at least global in one translation unit, and then you can have a function to close just that file that are called from a global `clean_all` function. The same with memory you allocate.

Comment: On the other hand, if you just open files and then don't close them or allocate memory but never free it, even when you're done with the files or memory, you have resource leaks, and that will come back and bite you in the rear parts sooner or later.

Comment: @this Maybe it's ok in that way, but I am trying to do in the best way possible because it is a project for the university.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I know, but I am asked to do  it anyway.

Comment: Do what @JoachimPileborg recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a static pointer inside a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void atexit_clean(void *data);

static void clean(void)
{
    atexit_clean(NULL);
}

void atexit_clean(void *data)
{
    static void *x;

    if (data) {
        x = data;
        atexit(clean);
    } else {
        free(x);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));

    atexit_clean(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Another method using a single global variable: you can store all objects to be freed in an array of pointers or a linked list, this example uses `realloc` (doesn't check (m/re)alloc for brevity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void **vclean;
static size_t nclean;

void atexit_add(void *data)
{
    vclean = realloc(vclean, sizeof(void *) * (nclean + 1));
    vclean[nclean++] = data;
}

void clean(void)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nclean; i++) {
        free(vclean[i]);
    }
    free(vclean);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    double *d;
    int e = 1;

    atexit(clean);
    a = &e;
    b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    atexit_add(b);
    c = malloc(sizeof(int));
    atexit_add(c);
    d = malloc(sizeof(double));
    atexit_add(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should move `atexit(clean_all);` to the start of the `main()` function. For a realistic example there could be operations that terminate the program between the calls to `atexit_add()`.

Comment: @Kay, that depends on whether you want to leave in a clean way or aborting, but in general you're right, edited.

Comment: `atexit_add()` should check for `realloc()` failure and return an error indication to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to pass any parameters to `atexit()`, so you're stuck using global variables.

When your program terminates normally, through `exit()` or by returning from `main()`, it will automatically flush and close any open streams and (under most operating systems) free allocated memory. However, it is good practice to explicitly clean up your resources before the program terminates, because it typically leads to a more structured program. *Sometimes* the cleanest way to write your program is to just exit and leave the cleanup to the implementation.

But be warned that you should **always** check the return value of `fclose()`. See "[What are the reasons to check for error on close()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24479705/3478852)" for an anecdote about what could happen when you don't.

Comment: Just note that the C standard does not *require* implementations free allocated memory. Indeed, a common problem for the TI-89 series is C programs not cleaning up before exit, and the OS did *not* clean up, thus repeated executions of a leaky program would exhaust RAM on the calculator.